# programmatically add parameters to URL java

Tags: java, url

i have a java application in which i want to programmatically add URL parameters to a given base url, instead of string manipulation to form a url. i have heard that URIBuilder is the way to go, though I have not been able to get that class or the maven repository to that class anywhere? is that the way to go or is there any other method to get that done?

EDIT: i have heard of using apache http client utils URIBuilder and not the javax.ws URIBuilder class

Comment: which java version u are using i am able to find see the link  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html

Answer (score 1):

Drop this dependency in your pom to get `UriBuilder`:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version><!-- Select the version you want here -->
 </dependency>
```

More info: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api

The Apache version is part of the httpcomponents:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

More info: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/

Comment: not the class i have heard of using. have heard that URIBuilder class of apache http client utils is the way to go

Comment: @user2739737 I have added the URIBuilder from apache.

Comment: i tried that repo. i was still unable to get the URIBuilder class.

Comment: @user2739737 What is a *repo* for you? `org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder` is located in this dependency.

Comment: i could not find the class URIBuilder within org.apache.http.client.utils

Comment: @user2739737 Check the version of `httpclient`

Comment: i added 4.3.1 in the dependency in pom.xml. does it have to be the same in the ht httpclient ? i have 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.net.URL` to create a URL.  The `set()` method allows you to set query parameters.

Comment: i could not find the set() method anywhere, though it has an addParameter() method. i'll try that. just one question: how to set the host/base url of the Url?

Comment: `set()` method in `java.net.URL` is not public. you cannot use in your package.